# Search field kicks me out on input field after 1 letter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

this is in React. I have a search input field, however after typing one letter it keeps me out of the input field and renders the page again. The search field does work, it just kicks me out. I've tried adding a

```
onChange={(e) => setSearchField(e.target.value), function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}}
```

to the input field but it doesn't work. Here's my whole file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col, Input } from "reactstrap";
import MeetingTable from "./MeetingTable";
import MeetingCreate from "./MeetingCreate";
import MeetingEdit from "./MeetingEdit";
import APIURL from "../helpers/environment";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./MeetingMain.css";

const MeetingMain = (props) => {
  const Div = styled.div`
    background-color: #363136;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  `;

  const [meetings, setMeetings] = useState([]);
  const [updateActive, setUpdateActive] = useState(false);
  const [meetingToUpdate, setMeetingToUpdate] = useState({});
  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("");

  const tableStyle = {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    maxWidth: "1175px",
  };

  const fetchMeetings = () => {
    fetch(`${APIURL}/meeting`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: props.token,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((logData) => {
        setMeetings(logData.meetings);
        console.log(logData.meetings);
      });
  };

  const editUpdateMeeting = (meeting) => {
    setMeetingToUpdate(meeting);
    console.log(meeting);
  };

  const updateOn = () => {
    setUpdateActive(true);
  };

  const updateOff = () => {
    setUpdateActive(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchMeetings();
  }, []);

  const filteredMeetings = meetings.filter((meeting) =>
    meeting.day.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
  );

  return (
    <Div>
      <Container style={tableStyle}>
        <Row>
          <Col md="12">
            <MeetingCreate fetchMeetings={fetchMeetings} token={props.token} />
          </Col>
          <Col md="12">
            <Input
              className="search-field"
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search Meetings"
              onChange={(e) => setSearchField(e.target.value)}
              value={searchField}
            />
            <MeetingTable
              meetings={filteredMeetings}
              editUpdateMeeting={editUpdateMeeting}
              updateOn={updateOn}
              fetchMeetings={fetchMeetings}
              token={props.token}
            />
          </Col>
          {updateActive ? (
            <MeetingEdit
              meetingToUpdate={meetingToUpdate}
              updateOff={updateOff}
              token={props.token}
              fetchMeetings={fetchMeetings}
            />
          ) : (
            <></>
          )}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Div>
  );
};

export default MeetingMain;
```

So I'm a bit at a loss on what's causing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

## Issue

You're defining a styled component *inside* your functional component, this means it's a ***new*** component each render cycle. In other words, it is a new component and mounted & rendered versus just being rerendered when state updates from the `onChange` handler.

[Define Styled Components outside of the render method](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#define-styled-components-outside-of-the-render-method)

> It is important to define your styled components outside of the render
> method, otherwise it will be recreated on every single render pass.
> Defining a styled component within the render method will thwart
> caching and drastically slow down rendering speed, and should be
> avoided.

**Recall:** The ***entire*** body of a functional component ***IS*** the render "method".

## Solution

Declare the `Div` component outside `MeetingMain` so it is a stable component reference.

```
const Div = styled.div`
  background-color: #363136;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
`;

const MeetingMain = (props) => {
  const [meetings, setMeetings] = useState([]);
  const [updateActive, setUpdateActive] = useState(false);
  const [meetingToUpdate, setMeetingToUpdate] = useState({});
  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should move `Div` outside of your `MeetingMain` component as below.

```js
const Div = styled.div`
    background-color: #363136;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  `;

const MeetingMain = (props) => {
    ...
}
```

Check it out [here](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3117#issuecomment-618070880)